# Codename One - "Done" button of iOS virtual keyboard

Tags: codenameone

The "Done" button on iOS virtual keyboard is too dark in my Codename One app (it's blue over a dark background). Is it possible to style it and its background? Or is it possible to remove it in all the app, without using iosHideToolbar for every text field?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Yes, of course: https://snag.gy/eymUaf.jpg (as you can see, the Done is blue and the background is black, can I change the color of the Done button?)

Comment: I suggest filing an RFE, we can probably provide a build hint to customize the color of this entry

Comment: Ok, I've filed it: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to disable it globally but there probably should be. I'll make this work for the next update of the build servers:

```
Display.getInstance().setProperty("iosHideToolbar", "true");
```